# Repeated command in output for Zsh prompt

Tags: zsh

In the output of any command I put into the prompt, that command is repeated (sometimes partially). What extremely simple configuration for Zsh do I need to enter to remove this repeat?

Example:

```
user ~ ls
lsDesktop Downloads src
```

Comment: Do you use colors in your prompt? [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957435/zsh-auto-complete-screws-up-command-name/10644062#10644062) *might* be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* have a hook-like function doing that, or your prompt is doing it.

I suggest reviewing your configuration files.

FWIW, If you start a new shell with `zsh -f`, it will skip your configuration files and won't be echo'ing the commands anymore.

Comment: I am using oh-my-zsh, so the default configuration files for that is being used (along with color changes). I searched through the .zshrc and associated oh-my-zsh configs but could not see any option related to a repeated input.

Comment: Turns out that there was a hidden configuration in a separate oh-my-zsh folder, thanks.