# zsh: command issued gets repeated in output

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, zsh

I'm having an issue identical to:
[Repeated command in output for zsh prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/514888/repeated-command-in-output-for-zsh-prompt). As in, the command I execute is being repeated on the next line, and then the output of the command follows.

But unfortunately the OP of that question didn't specify what configuration file was responsible for the issue. I looked through my `.oh-my-zsh/` folder and didn't find anything (not to say there are lots of files to look through) suspicious. I tried disabling all plugins and changing themes, but to no avail. Only running `zsh -f` (don't read config files) makes the issue go away. I'm using Xubuntu 64-bit that only has zsh 5.0.2 in the repositories, so I compiled zsh 5.2 on my own and tried with that, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved - turns out the culprit was wrong terminal name. I was playing around with GNU Screen earlier, and forced the `$TERM` variable to have other than default value (`screen-256color` instead of `rxvt-unicode-256color`) for my emulator. I did that in `.Xresources`. When I commented out the line, letting the emulator set `$TERM` appropriately, the issue was resolved.